# Unwanted space in the beginning of first line by ntheorem

Tags: spacing, ntheorem

How to avoid the space in the beginning of first line  by ntheorem

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=94mm,paperheight=50mm,margin=2mm,footskip=2mm,showframe
] {geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\vartriangleleft}}
\newtheorem{mythm}{}
%
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{mythm}
Some text\\
Some other text
\[
a = b
\]
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nonumberplain` style expects the theorem to have a heading specified by the second argument to `\newtheorem`, and inserts some space that is meant to go between this heading and the body of the theorem.

You can see the definition of nonumberplain style on page 52 of the [ntheorem documentation](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem/ntheorem.pdf).

I suppose a way around this would be to define another theorem style similar to it but without the `\hskip`s, and use it for your no-heading-no-number-theorems:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth=94mm,paperheight=50mm,margin=2mm,footskip=2mm,showframe
] {geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
%
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{nonumbernoheading}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont##1\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont##1\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{nonumbernoheading}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\vartriangleleft}}
\newtheorem{mythm}{}
%
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{mythm}
Some text\\
Some other text
\[
a = b
\]
\end{mythm}
\end{document}
```

[image: new theorem style output]